# Devel user & decrease number queries

Tags: 7, performance, debugging

I'm trying to decrease the number of my queries with the devel module but I have two questions.

1) Why do I have 281 dblog_watchdog queries? How can I get rid of them? 
Why should I keep them, I already have the apache logs?

```
INSERT INTO watchdog (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9)
```

2) How to show the number of queries for anonymous users?
Right know it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Disable database log module, it will stop all watchdog queries. Its a PITA for big sites, and DB size will also increase. Check permissions page for granting permissions to anonymous user under devel section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) By default, *dblog* module is enabled. It is real performance bottleneck for big sites. But you can use [syslog](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/syslog) module (from core) or contrib analogs to write logs in /var/log/drupal.log and etc.
Rsyslog config can be something like this:

```
    local0.warning /var/log/drupal_site_err.log
    local0.info;local0.!warning /var/log/drupal_site.log
```

You should **analize** your logs and **fix** errors, warnings and even PHP notices. I think 281 messages per page — this is a lot.

2) On your dev site you can allow anonymous users to see devel information with permission “Access developer information”. Don't forget to disallow Devel on production.

Comment: I have a page on how to find the php errors that repeat the most first http://groups.drupal.org/node/170339 I run this query in something like phpmyadmin